# Why is my hash value off did I do something wrong with my code?

Tags: python, user-interface, hash, sha256, sha

I am writing a SHA256 Hash function and it's mostly complete but when I run the code the hash is way to high and it's not correct. What is wrong with my code that's making it far off from the actual value to be? Now keep in mind I do not have a chunk loop so it might look a bit different. This also A GUI as well.

```
      #VARIABLES
      FF = (1 >> 32)-1
      #Right rotate
      def rr(a,b):
        return((a >> b) | (a << (32 - b))) & FF
      
      h0 = 0x6a09e667
      h1 = 0xbb67ae85
      h2 = 0x3c6ef372
      h3 = 0xa54ff53a
      h4 = 0x510e527f
      h5 = 0x9b05688c
      h6 = 0x1f83d9ab
      h7 = 0x5be0cd19
      
      #Messages
      word_Hash = "1: Please write below what\n word you would like to hash."
      
      
      
      
      words = []
      playerinput = []
      varwords = [word_Hash]
      
      #FUNCTIONS
      count = 0
      
      def SHA256():
        global playerinput, wordtohash, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
      #get input
        wordtohash = playerinput.pop(0)
       #convert to binary
        BinaryConversion = ''.join(format(ord(i), '08b') for i in wordtohash) + "1"
          #pad helped by Dr.Glynn, Maple
        if len(BinaryConversion) <= 512:
            count = len(BinaryConversion)
            while count <= 448:
              BinaryConversion = BinaryConversion + "0"
              count += 1
            wordtohash = len(wordtohash)
            endofpad = int(wordtohash) * 8
            
            numberofzeros = 0
            while numberofzeros < 63 - int(len(bin(endofpad)[2:])):
              BinaryConversion = BinaryConversion + "0"
              numberofzeros += 1
      
            #BinaryConversion = (BinaryConversion) +  str(endofpad)
      
            BinaryConversion = str(BinaryConversion) + str(bin(endofpad)[2:])
            #numbers = len(BinaryConversion)
            #print(BinaryConversion)
             #first 16 messages
      
      
      
      
            w = [int('0b'+BinaryConversion[0:31], 2),   
                 int('0b'+BinaryConversion[32:63], 2),
                 int('0b'+BinaryConversion[64:95],2),
                 int('0b'+BinaryConversion[96:127],2),
                 int('0b'+BinaryConversion[128:159],2),
                 int('0b'+BinaryConversion[160:191],2),
                 int('0b'+BinaryConversion[192:223],2),
                 int('0b'+BinaryConversion[224:255],2),
                 int('0b'+BinaryConversion[256:287],2),
                 int('0b'+BinaryConversion[288:319],2),
                 int('0b'+BinaryConversion[320:351],2),
                 int('0b'+BinaryConversion[352:383],2),
                 int('0b'+BinaryConversion[384:415],2),
                 int('0b'+BinaryConversion[416:447],2),
                 int('0b'+BinaryConversion[448:479],2),
                 int('0b'+BinaryConversion[480:511],2)]
         
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
          
          
            #Message Scedule
            #rest of the messages
      
            for c in range(16,64):
              
              S0 = rr(w[c-15], 7) ^ rr(w[c-15], 18)  ^ (w[c-15] >> 3)
      
              S1 = rr(w[c - 2], 17) ^ rr(w[c - 2], 19) ^ (w[c - 2] >> 10)
      
              w.append((w[c - 16] + S0 + w[c-7] + S1) & FF)
      
            print(w)
      
            A = h0
            B = h1
            C = h2
            D = h3
            E = h4
            F = h5
            G = h6
            H = h7
            
            for i in range(64):
              s1 = rr(E, 6) ^ rr(E, 11) ^ rr(E, 25)
              ch = (E & F) ^ (~E & G)
              temp1 = H + s1 + ch + K[i] + w[i]
              s0 = rr(A, 2) ^ rr(A, 13) ^ rr(A, 22)
              maj = (A & B) ^ (A & C) ^ (B & C)
              temp2 = s0 + maj
              H = G
              G = F
              F = E
              E = D + temp1
              D = C
              C = B
              B = A
              A = temp1 + temp2
              
            A = hex(A)[2:]
            B = hex(B)[2:]
            C = hex(C)[2:]
            D = hex(D)[2:]
            E = hex(E)[2:]
            F = hex(F)[2:]
            G = hex(G)[2:]
            H = hex(H)[2:]
      
            print(A)
      
      
      
      
      
      
      def finish():
        global count, varwords, playerinput, words
        if count >= 1:
          screenframe1.pack_forget()
          frm_screen2.pack()
          SHA256()  
      
          lbl_story["text"] = "Your word is {}\n Your hash value is {}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}".format(wordtohash,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)
```

Comment: There are numerous open source sha-256 implementations, I suggest you find one and step through it with a debugger to find the first place where they disagree, then fix your bug, then repeat.

Comment: So there is an issue with the conversions to the words which is throwing the conversion off for w but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged your code, there was many mistakes,

1. w list was wrongly initialized
2. you didn't use the modulo operator. Without modulo, your numbers are way too large.
3. FF = (1 >> 32)-1 isn't correct. I changed it to `UINT32_MAX = 2**32`, UINT32 means unsigned 32-bit integer. Max is the maximum limit of a 32-bit unsigned integer.

It took me an hour to debug so upvote if you found it helpful. Here is the code:

```
#VARIABLES
UINT32_MAX = 2**32
#Right rotate
def rr(a,b):
    return((a >> b) | (a << (32 - b))) & UINT32_MAX



# 2^32 times the cube root of the first 64 primes
K = [
0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5, 0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1,
0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5, 0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3,
0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174, 0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786,
0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc, 0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7, 0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147,
0x06ca6351, 0x14292967, 0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13,
0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85, 0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b,
0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3, 0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5, 0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a,
0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3, 0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208,
0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2
]

#Messages
word_Hash = "1: Please write below what\n word you would like to hash."

UINT32_MAX = 0xffffffff

words = []
playerinput = ["test"]
varwords = [word_Hash]

#FUNCTIONS
count = 0
      
def SHA256():
    h0 = 0x6a09e667
    h1 = 0xbb67ae85
    h2 = 0x3c6ef372
    h3 = 0xa54ff53a
    h4 = 0x510e527f
    h5 = 0x9b05688c
    h6 = 0x1f83d9ab
    h7 = 0x5be0cd19
    
    global playerinput, wordtohash, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
    #get input
    wordtohash = playerinput.pop(0)
     #convert to binary
    BinaryConversion = ''.join(format(ord(i), '08b') for i in wordtohash) + "1"
    #pad helped by Dr.Glynn, Maple
    if len(BinaryConversion) <= 512:
        count = len(BinaryConversion)
        while count <= 448:
            BinaryConversion = BinaryConversion + "0"
            count += 1
        wordtohash = len(wordtohash)
        endofpad = int(wordtohash) * 8
        
        numberofzeros = 0
        while numberofzeros < 63 - int(len(bin(endofpad)[2:])):
            BinaryConversion = BinaryConversion + "0"
            numberofzeros += 1
    
        BinaryConversion = str(BinaryConversion) + str(bin(endofpad)[2:])

        # first 16 messages
        w = [int(BinaryConversion[i:i+32], 2) for i in range(0, len(BinaryConversion), 32)]
       
        #Message Scedule
        #rest of the messages
        for c in range(16,64):
            S0 = rr(w[c-15], 7) ^ rr(w[c-15], 18)  ^ (w[c-15] >> 3)
            S1 = rr(w[c - 2], 17) ^ rr(w[c - 2], 19) ^ (w[c - 2] >> 10)
            w.append((w[c - 16] + S0 + w[c-7] + S1) & UINT32_MAX)
    
        A = h0
        B = h1
        C = h2
        D = h3
        E = h4
        F = h5
        G = h6
        H = h7
        
        for i in range(64):
            s1 = (rr(E, 6) ^ rr(E, 11) ^ rr(E, 25))
            ch = (E & F) ^ (~E & G)
            temp1 = (H + s1 + ch + K[i] + w[i])%(UINT32_MAX+1)
            s0 = (rr(A, 2) ^ rr(A, 13) ^ rr(A, 22))
            maj = (A & B) ^ (A & C) ^ (B & C)
            temp2 = (s0 + maj)%(UINT32_MAX+1)
            H = G
            G = F
            F = E
            E = (D + temp1)%(UINT32_MAX+1)
            D = C
            C = B
            B = A
            A = (temp1 + temp2)%(UINT32_MAX+1)
        h0 = (A + h0)%(UINT32_MAX+1)
        h1 = (B + h1)%(UINT32_MAX+1)
        h2 = (C + h2)%(UINT32_MAX+1)
        h3 = (D + h3)%(UINT32_MAX+1)
        h4 = (E + h4)%(UINT32_MAX+1)
        h5 = (F + h5)%(UINT32_MAX+1)
        h6 = (G + h6)%(UINT32_MAX+1)
        h7 = (H + h7)%(UINT32_MAX+1)
          
        h0 = hex(h0)[2:]
        h1 = hex(h1)[2:]
        h2 = hex(h2)[2:]
        h3 = hex(h3)[2:]
        h4 = hex(h4)[2:]
        h5 = hex(h5)[2:]
        h6 = hex(h6)[2:]
        h7 = hex(h7)[2:]
        print("hash: {}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}".format(h0,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7))


def finish():
    global count, varwords, playerinput, words
    if count >= 1:
        screenframe1.pack_forget()
        frm_screen2.pack()
        SHA256()  

        lbl_story["text"] = "Your word is {}\n Your hash value is {}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}".format(wordtohash,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)
SHA256()
```